# Media query for retina and non-retina so only one graphic is loaded

Tags: css, retina

When I write media queries I always specify both the min and max so that I don't override the CSS for a background image when the device is at a certain size, instead it just loads the one I want.

So:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) { background-image: url(''); }
@media (min-width: 768px) { background-image: url(''); }
```

instead of:

```
background-image: url('');
@media (min-width: 768px) { background-image: url(''); }
```

*Note: I use SCSS so the above nested syntax is valid.*

However when it comes to retina...

How do I do the same pattern? So instead of overriding the image like:

```
background-image: url('');
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 2dppx) { background-image: url(''); }
```

I want do something more like:

```
@media (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (max-resolution: 2dppx) { background-image: url(''); }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 2dppx) { background-image: url(''); }
```

But what do I set the max one to? as usually you just go one pixel below your min to prevent the double breakpoint issue. What would the resolution need to be? `1.9dppx` and `1.9` ratio?

**Update: it looks like you don't need to do the same as pixels to prevent double breakpoint for the resolution and it works as is.**